# replace space with hyphens for url, then remove hyphens for query (unless they were there to begin with...)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

So I have some code that pulls data from the 'products' table in my database, and displays it like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $group[ $row['companyname'] ][] = $row;
}
foreach ($group as $company_name => $products) {
    echo "$company_name";
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            echo "<a href='/products/$product[id]/$product[companyname]/$product[itemname]'>";
                echo "<img src='$image_dir_url'>";
            echo '</a>';
        }
}
```

To make that link work, I have a rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /products/index.php?id=$1&company=$2&itemname=$3 [L]
```

and then later in the code

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['company']) && isset($_GET['itemname'])) {
    display that items data
}
```

This works great and gives me urls such as:

www.mysite.com/products/5311/company name/item name

instead of

www.mysite.com/products/index.php?id=5311&company=company name&itemname=item name

However, and here comes my problem, I also need to add dashes in any whitespace for the url, to make it look like this:

www.mysite.com/products/5311/company-name/item-name

I thought I had this solved and I was actually really happy with myself (I am quite a newbie at this):

I simply added:

```
$company = str_replace(' ', '-', $product['companyname']);
$item = str_replace(' ', '-', $product['itemname']);
```

And used those variables to generate the link.

Then used the opposite to fix them back up for the database query:

```
str_replace('-', ' ', $company);
```

Now, as I said, I thought this was really good and it all worked fine...

Until I realized some of my companies and products *have hyphens in their names to begin with*.

So adding hyphens to all the spaces in companies/products that have spaces *works*, but when I remove all of the hyphens for the query, companies/products that had
hyphen/s initially lose them! Thus they do not get retrieved by my query anymore.

Craaaap.

Is there any way around this, or should I just create a new field in my products database called rewrite_url and use that for my link and check for that in my database to look the item up? Any advice would be appreciated, I barely
slept last night because this was going around in my head.

Comment: A fast & simple answer would be to use another character that is not present in companies name (other than hyphen). This way you could "encode" and "decode" urls easily

Comment: I thought about this but everything I've read says that hyphens are best for word separation in URLS. Underscores etc don't act the same apparently.

Comment: True but underscores are still fine in my own opinion

Comment: Why don't you just URL-encode properly? Spaces will be turned into `+`, and this will be decoded on the server automatically.

Comment: @Barmar, honestly I am new to this and this is the only method I have tried. I am open to any other methods, for sure :)